# Why most people use getaddrinfo for dns query?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, dns, posix

I'm now doing some dns query works, in order to get the ttl of domain, i used ns struct defined in nameser.h, but when I search dns relative codes, I found people used getaddrinfo mostly, even in google chromium, it used getaddrinfo for dns too, I am now wondering why? Is ns struct and function for it (like ns_parserr, ns_rr_rdata, res_query) is unsafe or too complex? please tell me its weakness whether is it safe and can be used on linux, mac, and win?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, getaddrinfo is much simpler to use then querying the nameserver - and simpler to use means less bugs.

Then, getaddrinfo does much more than simply querying the nameserver. Depending on the system and system configuration it includes the hosts file, can integrate with dictionary services like NIS, makes use of system wide preferences about which nameservers are used, which domains are searched when no FQDN is given, how results are ordered regarding IPv4 and IPv6 preferences ... .

And it is the standard interface defined by POSIX and in [RFC 2553](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2553).

Comment: Thanks a lot, apart from that, can you tell me some potential bugs using ns struct(since you said there are less bugs using getaddrinfo) and  is it ok and safe to use ns struct and its function defined in namser?

Comment: @Rosonlee: I did not say that using ns struct implies bugs but that using getaddrinfo is simpler and that simpler code also usually means less bugs. *"is it ok and safe to use ns struct and its function defined in namser"* - if you understand what you are doing and are able to  manage the complexity and if your use case make getaddrinfo a bad choice, then it is ok. If it is secure depends on your experience.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, since I need to get ttl of domain, it seems I have to use ns instead of getaddrinfo, thanks a lot.

Comment: There are also other modern high levels API like https://getdnsapi.net/documentation/spec/ that are tailored to modern needs like DNSSEC, etc.